# Give a possible description of $\alpha^{(k)}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let the sequence $\alpha^{(k)}$ be written as \begin{align*}\alpha^{(1)} &= 000000\\\alpha^{(2)} &= 100000\\\alpha^{(3)} &= 020000\\\alpha^{(4)} &= 120000\\\alpha^{(5)} &= 013000\\\alpha^{(6)} &= 113000\\\alpha^{(7)} &= 002400\\\alpha^{(8)} &= 102400\\\alpha^{(9)} &= 022400\\\alpha^{(10)} &= 122400,\\&\vdots\end{align*} where the number of zeros at the end of each $\alpha^{(k)}$ is unending. Give a possible description of $\alpha^{(k)}$.

The $\alpha^{(k)}$ have digit sum equal to $k-1$ and seem to have digits listed in ascending order. We can write $\alpha^{(k)}$ as a permutation of the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$. How can we find a formula for $\alpha^{(k)}$?

Answer (score 0):

This rule seems to work:

$a_0 = 0000....$

If $a_{n-1} = x_0x_1x_2......$, then, let $k$ be the first digit which is zero. Then, define the operation $F: \{\textrm{ tuples }\} \to \{\textrm{tuples} \}$ by:

$x_{k} \mapsto x_{k-1} + 1$, $x_{k-1} \mapsto \Sigma_{i=0}^{k-2} x_i$, $F(x_0) = ... F(x_{k-2}) = 0$, $F(x_i) = x_i$ for all $i > k$.

Then, set $a_n = F(x_0)F(x_1)...$

---

Note that with my construction, it is obvious that the sum of digits of $a_n$ is equal to $1$ plus the sum of digits of $a_{n-1}$.